# undefined method `tripphoto_changed?' for ... Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I'm trying to save an image when adding a new Trip via an association.

tripphoto.rb has a `belongs_to :trip`

and my trip.rb has a `has_many :tripphotos`. Furthermore the Carrierwave documentation requires a few more things like an uploader and such which I've set up correctly (It worked without the association!).

Along with it I've got `mount_uploader :tripphoto, TripphotoUploader` in my trip.rb and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :tripphotos, allow_destroy: true` to get my form working properly as such:

```
    <%= fields_for :tripphotos do |photo| %>
      Img <%= photo.file_field :filename %>
    <% end %>
```

Nonetheless I get the error `undefined method`tripphoto_changed?' for #`. A quick Google has no fitting result. Any advice?

P.S here's my Tripphoto table:

```
class Tripphoto < ActiveRecord::Base {
    :id => :integer,
    :filename => :string,
    :trip_id => :integer,
    :created_at => :datetime,
    :updated_at => :datetime
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Edit: On request my Codes:

Trip.rb

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :title, :user_id, 
  :triplocations_attributes, :photo, :category_ids, 
  :start_city, :tripphotos, :img_url, :thumb_url, :images,
  :tags_attributes

  # validates :title, :length => {:minimum => 3}
  # validates :description, :presence => true
  # validates_associated :tags


  has_many :triplocations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tripphotos, :dependent => :destroy

  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :triplocations, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tripphotos, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags


  mount_uploader :tripphoto, TripphotoUploader
end
```

Tripphoto.rb

```
class Tripphoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :filename, :trip_id
  belongs_to :trip
end
```

The complete trip form

```
<%= form_for @trip, :html => {:multipart => true} do |a| %> 
    <%= a.label :title, "Routetitel" %>
    <%= a.text_field :title %>

    <%= a.label :description, "Omschrijving" %>
    <%= a.text_area :description %>

    <%= a.label :start_city, "Stad" %>
    <%= a.text_field :start_city, :id => "cityName" %>

    <% for category in Category.find(:all) %>
        <div>
          <%= check_box_tag "trip[category_ids][]", category.id, @trip.categories.include?(category) %>
          <%= category.name %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= a.fields_for :tags do |f| %>
        <p>
            <%= f.label :title, 'Steekwoorden:' %>
            <%= f.text_field :title %>
        </p> 
        <div id="inputFields"></div>

    <% end %>
    <div style="background: red;">
        <%= fields_for :tripphotos do |photo| %>
          Img <%= photo.file_field :filename %>
        <% end %>
    </div>


    <%= a.submit 'Verstuur' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please post the code of your two models `Trip` & `Tripphoto`. And could you also post the beggining of your form ? not only the `fields_for` part ?

Comment: THanks for your reply. Please see my revised question above!

Comment: First problem I see is that you should mount the uploader on the field that will store the file name, here it's `filename` in `Tripphoto`, and not as you did on the model tripphoto in the `Trip` model

Comment: Well, that was dumb. The error is gone now. The image is not being saved in the database nor in my public/uploads dir though.

Comment: You could check in your server log what's happening when submitting the form, are the params correctly received by your controller ? do you see some warning such as `cannot mass assign ...`, are there any SQL rollbacks ...

Comment: It appears the tripphoto is being made outside the trip params: `"trip"=>{"title"=>"sadsa", "description"=>"dsadsad", "start_city"=>"Franeker", "tags_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"title"=>"sdasd"}}}, "tripphotos"=>{"filename"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000000214a490 @original_filename="220px-Paatje_Phefferkorn.jpg"`

Comment: That's because you forgot the `a.` in front of `fields_for`, see what you did for the tags

Comment: if you don't mind, I'll post that as an answer below, so it'll be more obvious for other people facing the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems here :

- you should mount the uploader on the field that will store the file name, the `filename` field in the `Tripphoto` model in that case, and not the `tripphoto` association.
- you forgot the `a.` in front of `fields_for`, see what you did for the tags

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem,

For me it was that I forgot to ran:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

That was the reason about the youruploaderattributte_changed? Missing Method in the moodel.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, caused by a little stupid mistake of mine. First I run

```
rails generate uploader Photo
```

and set

```
mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
```

in the model. But then I used "avatar" instead of "photo" in the migration:

```
rails g migration add_avatar_to_users avatar:string
```

That was stupid! Eh eh eh ;-)